# TLS Session Tickets: What is the risk of a disclosed server ticket key?

Tags: tls, session-management

So there is this TLS Session resumption method using Session Tickets which transfers the TLS server secret state to the client (encrypted and authenticated with a key only known to the server)

If a client wants to resume a session, he simply includes the Session Ticket in the request, which allows the server to resume the session.

Questions:

- What happens if the Session key (server) is stolen?
- What could an attacker do if he records **ALL** packets between the server and various clients? Will he be able to decrypt everything?

The Session Ticket includes the `master_secret` (which is used for symmetric crypto like AES?) ([RFC 5077, page 11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5077#page-11)).

- How exactly is this `master_secret` reused after Session resumption?
  Will server and client continue to reuse this `master_secret` for all symmetric crypto (e.g. AES)?

Answer (score 6):

## Ticket crypto broken -> PFS broken.

I believe this quote from a great CloudFlare blog post answers each of your questions.

- Zi Lin, CloudFlare, Inc., 2015-02-24, *[TLS Session Resumption: Full-speed and Secure](https://blog.cloudflare.com/tls-session-resumption-full-speed-and-secure/)*

> this key becomes [a] critical single point of failure for TLS security: if an adversary gets hold of it, the session key information is exposed for every session ticket! Even after the lifetime of a session ticket, such a loss would invalidate supposed “perfect forward secrecy” (as evangelized here on our blog).
>
> Therefore, it is important to:
> “generate session ticket keys randomly, distribute them to the servers without ever touching persistent storage and rotate them frequently.” (Adam Langley)

And they link to a blog post by Adam Langley that gives background for this:

- Adam Langley, 2013-06-27, *[How to botch TLS forward secrecy](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2013/06/27/botchingpfs.html)*